# how to fix the error in webdriver selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have a project (in python) that requires opening a url, login to the website and to click on elements in tha page. I tried doing it with webdriver and it worked until the update of chrome and then I had this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version 
of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 100.0.4896.75 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I tried to move to webbrowser but this library is useless for working with elements on the page.. Can you help me to fix the error in the webdriver? I tried to download the right version of webdriver but I didnt understand what I need to do next..

[The new chromeDriver I download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDYMh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the version 100 of Chromedriver on this site
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
Then you need to delete the old version and place the new version where the old was, so you dont need to change the path

Comment: I already did this.. there is another thing I need to do after that? something in thr code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the corresponding ChromeDriver for your Chrome. Unfortunately, you have to do this every time you update your browser :(

Check for Chrome Version 100 on [this page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Looks like [this one](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/).

Comment: I already did this.. there is another thing I need to do after that? something in the code?

Comment: Did you install the driver in your PATH? Replace the old driver there?